# Is there a way to execute a linux command from Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, plugins

I have a project that i set up in eclipse . Everything works fine except that i have to keep going back to my terminal to use the proprietary  versioning system we have here. Is there a way for me to use to issue linux shell commands from within eclipse ?

Is there like a generic plugin that executes linux commands or will i have to write my own plugin to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Run>External Tools>External Tools Configurations* to create launch configs that will execute commands (usually via System.exec(*)).  You can use executables directly, or execute scripts via an appropriate interpreter (like `/bin/bash /lib/myScript.sh`)

PW

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Remote System Explorer (RSE) framework provided under the [Target Management](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) project of Eclipse for accessing a remote or local machine from a shell.

Although the name might suggest that it might not be useful to run local commands, it is very well possible to do so. If you have to connect to remote systems from Eclipse, then it would be the suitable plug-in to use.